# Why are titles written top to bottom on the spine of English books, while they are written bottom to top on the spine of French books?

Tags: physical-books

I have a bunch of books in French and a bunch of books in English. I mix them all in my bookshelf. But it's very annoying because I have to tilt my head to the right to read English titles, and to the left to read French titles.

I was wondering if there was any interesting story behind that difference in convention.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but we had some discussion about this in chat at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55737317#55737317 .  We got the question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/143242/15123 from it.

Comment: It's also annoying when you need to stack a pile of books on their backs; French ones have their titles upside down. I don't know the reason either.